# TryParseExact / ParseExact in .net to match this date time 2021-03-04T17:00:0s.000Z

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Can anyone help me work out what the Patten would be to match this date time

`2021-03-04T17:00:0s.000Z`

```
var dateValue = "2021-03-04T17:00:0s.000Z";
string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:s's'.fff'Z'";
DateTime parsedDate;

var datetime = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

This is my attempt but its not working.

Thanks for any help

Comment: And what `hh` means ? does `17` fit `hh` ? (I don't think so)

Comment: where did you even find such a format?

Comment: `0s.000Z` is non-standard and very unusual. That's not an ISO8601 string. All applications, no matter what language they were written on, will choke on this. It's better to fix whatever produced this unusual string.

Comment: The date is being provided by a third party shipping service.  I am kind of stuck with it.  Need to parse it into a .net DateTime.

Comment: I suspect this was produced by a formatting bug, eg using `sss` instead of `ss`, or `s\s` when saving a date. Instead of trying to cover up the bug it's better to fix it.

Comment: @dx4100 file a bug then. If you pay them, they're obliged to fix this. What happens with `34` seconds ? Will you get `3s` or `34s` ?

Comment: @Selvin

Good spot - silly mistake

string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s's'.fff'Z'";

Its now giving me a useful output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s's'.fff'Z'";
```

But anyways, this is not a part of any date time standard. You should fix the source of this datetime string. It has a bug.

---

*UPDATE*

Another way to fix it is to replace the `s` character with a `0`:

```cs
var dateValue = "2021-03-04T17:00:0s.000Z".Replace('s', '0');
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateValue);
```

---

*UPDATE*

Here is a method to fix the string event if there is gonna be two numbers before `s`:

```cs
DateTime ParseCorruptedTime(string dateValue) {
    dateValue = dateValue.Replace("s", "");
    var colonIndex = dateValue.LastIndexOf(':');
    var dotIndex   = dateValue.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex - colonIndex < 3) {
        dateValue = dateValue.Insert(colonIndex + 1, "0");
    }
    return DateTime.Parse(dateValue);
}
```

```cs
var dateValue1 = "2021-03-04T17:00:5s.000Z";
var dateValue2 = "2021-03-04T17:00:56s.000Z";
var parsedDate1 = ParseCorruptedTime(dateValue1);
var parsedDate2 = ParseCorruptedTime(dateValue2);
```

This will produce the following output:

```
parsedDate1: 2021-03-04T17:00:05.000Z
parsedDate2: 2021-03-04T17:00:56.000Z
```

Comment: Yup I am raising a ticket with the provider.  Thanks

Comment: @dx4100 added a 100% method to fix the string (it has 2 string allocations though). You can safely use it while they fix the issue